# How to call function by order without calling setTimeout ? using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to call function only when is first function loaded ?
I have choice which work ( but not enough good for me )

```
 allData(){ 
 }
```

Do I have any better solution ?

Comment: how do you know when this.allData is finished? does it return a Promise? can it take a callback function? as is the answers are many and varied

Comment: please share implementation of `allData()` method

Comment: allData(){
        this.accountsService.getContactPerson().subscribe(
            (data: any) => { 
                console.log(data)     
            },
            (err: Error) => console.log(err)
        )
    }

Comment: this is allData function. Finished was go to subscribe data

Comment: put it in the question where it can be read - and what to do if there's an error

Comment: I don't have error.. I just need better solution .. maybe using rxjs flatMap ? i don;t know

Answer (score 1):

`allData()` performs an async operation so you need to call the second function when the `getContactPerson()` returns a value. In your case you need to call it in the `next` callback. Try to move the second function call inside the callback, as following:

```
allData(){ 
   this.accountsService
    .getContactPerson()
    .subscribe( 
       (data: any) => { 
         console.log(data)
         /* DO SOME STUFF HERE */

         this.lastAddedItem(this.contacts, contact);

       }, 
       (err: Error) => console.log(err) 
     ) 
} 


this.allData()
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to use the same function in `onInit` and after another event such as a button click, you can refactor you code to return an `Observable` and use it in multiple places.

```
allData = () => this.accountsService.getContactPerson();

ngOnInit(){
   this.allData().subscribe( 
       (data: any) => { /* DO SOME STUFF HERE */ }, 
       (err: Error) => console.log(err) 
     ) 
}

refreshList = () => {
   this.allData().subscribe( 
       (data: any) => { 

         /* DO SOME OTHER STUFF HERE */

         this.lastAddedItem(this.contacts, contact);

       }, 
       (err: Error) => console.log(err) 
     ) 
}


// This is just an example for an async call
anotherAsyncCall = () => {
   this.allData()
       .pipe(
          switchMap((result) => this.contactService.makeAsyncCall())
       )
       .subscribe()
}
```

Comment: I can't to do this. Because allData is loaded on init, but I need this call only on add new item in array...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. What do you mean by "allData is loaded on init"? What is the flow of your program?

Comment: allData is onInit function. I call allData also to refresh list.. I this case i want to refresh list and call lastAddedItem ... I wan't onInit to also call lastAddedItem

Comment: @fipodas I updated the answer trying to include what you need as far as I understand. Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not explain well unfortunately... i need to change question

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are getting `observable` from this `this.accountsService.getContactPerson()` method, so I will suggest you please try this approach.

```
async ngOnInit() {
   await this.loadAllData();
   this.lastAddedItem(this.contacts, contact);
}

public async loadAllData() {
    try {
        let allDataResponse$ = this.accountsService.getContactPerson();
        let allData = await lastValueFrom(allDataResponse$);
    
    } catch(e) {
       console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: allData is onInit function. I call allData also to refresh list.. I this case i want to refresh list and call lastAddedItem ... I wan't onInit to also call lastAddedItem

Comment: Alright! I modify my answer, please have a look, it may help you

Comment: I did not explain well unfortunately... i need to change question

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case for using `switchMap` operator. First of all, do not subscribe in `allData()` method, instead just return the observable:

```
allData() { 
    return this.accountsService.getContactPerson();
}
```

then, use `switchMap` where you are calling `allData()`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.allData().pipe(
        switchMap(data => {
            // Do what you want to with the data. 
            // I am assuming that the data is either assigned to contacts 
            // or contact ... but I am not sure. 

            // Return if this method also returns an observable.
            return this.lastAddedItem(this.contacts, contact);

            // otherwise comment the above line & uncomment the below line:
            // this.lastAddedItem(this.contacts, contact);
        }
    ).subscribe( ... );
```